# Unable to open SQL Server database file (.mdf)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 .mdf file that I am trying to open in SQL Server Management Studio so I can add a field to a table, but I am unable to open the file. I can't say that I really understand how SQL Server handles these databases. I especially don't understand the "attaching" and "detaching" operations.

I am working in VB.Net 2008 now, but my background is with VB6 using the JET engine. It was just so straightforward using the JET engine, but seems so much more complicated with SQL Server. I am trying to use .mdf files the same way I used .mdb files. I want my application to find the database file, "attach to it", and let me manipulate it.

At one time I was able to open my database in SQL Server Management Studio and edit the design of the database. The application still works but I am no longer able to modify the database because I cannot attach to it in Management Studio.

Here is a big clue: the files are no longer in the special folder anymore, which is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\`. I might have deleted the files, stupidly, thinking they were redundant. I still have the .mdf file (and the _log.ldf file) on my hard drive and the application can still open it, but when I try to use Management Studio to attach to the .mdf file, I get this error:

> Unable to open the physical file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\HEALSExamsSQL.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Indeed the file is not there, but why is Mgmt Studio looking there? Why doesn't it just open the file where it is? What can I do to get it back? I even copied the files to that folder but I get the same error.

Here is another clue: In Management Studio, when I right-click Databases, and chose Attach, it brings up a dialog. There I click "Add" to get another dialog in which I will select a database, but before the dialog appears I get this error:

> Locate Database Files - KURANT-WIN7\SQLEXPRESS
>   
> C:\Users\Jason Kurant\Desktop
>   
> Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists.
>   
> If you know that the service account can access a specific file, type in the full path for the file in the File Name control in the Locate dialog box.

This suggests to me that there is some access control issue, but I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

And how to view data in the .mdf file?

Comment: Are you logged in as Jason Kurant?

Answer (score 10):

> when I try to use Management Studio to attach to the .mdf file

There's not really a gentle way to say this: Stop doing that. The GUI is full of bugs and bad defaults; more importantly, unless you take a screencast, we have no way to identify exactly what steps you're taking as you point and click your way through the GUI.

1. Log in as a system administrator (preferably the `sa` account). If you're not a system administrator, or have lost the `sa` password, see [this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/) to get it back.
2. Make *sure* both files are in this location (you should never be pointing SQL Server at user folders like `...\Jason Kurant\...`):

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\

   Also run the following code to validate that the above *is* the right path:

   ```
   USE master;
   GO
   EXEC sp_helpfile;
   ```

   The location of these files should match. It's possible you have multiple instances of SQL Server and you are looking in the wrong instance's data folder.
3. Run the following code (or fix the paths to match the location of the `master` database above, if it is different):

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE HEALSExamsSQL
    ON (Name = HEALSExamsSQL_Data, FileName = 
     'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\mort.mdf')
    LOG ON (Name = HEALSExamsSQL__Log, FileName = 
     'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\mort_log.ldf')
   FOR ATTACH;
   ```

You may get an error message here. For example, the log file may not have been cleanly detached, in which case you can try changing `FOR ATTACH` to `FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`. If that doesn't work either, then it's possible your MDF file is corrupt too (we can speculate better if you get this far and share a more meaningful error message).

Ideally, you would go back to the original system and get a proper backup, then restore, not attach.

> I am trying to use .mdf files the same way I used .mdb files.

Well, they are not the same. This is similar to saying you want to use your tractor in a Nascar race, but drive it the same way you drive it on the farm, and expect to win. If you want to use SQL Server, you need to sit down and learn how SQL Server works, and forget about Access (which IMHO is not really a relational database platform, more of a glorified spreadsheet).

> I want my application to find the database file, "attach to it", and let me manipulate it.

You should be avoiding using MDF/LDF files as "backups" because they are anything but. Please read this post for more details:

- [Bad Habits : Using MDF/LDF Files as "Backups"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups)